# The error in simple Taylor's Polynomial with gap between power

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, geometric-series

Suppose we have this simple rational function and the expansion of it in few terms at the origin,

$$\frac{1}{1-x^4}= 1 + x^4 + \, ...$$

Now what happen if we want to compare the error between $n=2$ and $n=3$? It seems as if, when we are using Lagrange's Remainder, the error is actually reduced. Because the denominator increases with greater $n$. But we know even for $n=3$, we only have two terms. Can anyone spot where my misconception is? Or if this is not actually a problem because for $n < 4$, the error is always taken as the smallest one anyway i.e the error for $n=2$ and $n=3$ is always $R_3$? (Where $R_n$ is the Lagrange's Remainder).

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

When we use the formula for $n = 3$, we're using more information about the function than we do for $n = 2$, so it's no surprise that we're able to extract a tighter bound on the error in the former case.

Comment: So in a sense, the error is already that small but we just don't know it yet during the calculation when we are using $n = 2$ formula right?

Comment: Yes---the bounds on errors here are worst-case scenarios, and when we use more information (as we do when passing from the $n = 2$ estimate to the $n = 3$ estimate) we're restricting which scenarios occur, and thus how bad the worst case can be.

Comment: Oh, I forget to ask you something else in regard to this. So if one is asked to get the error for $n=2$, it is reasonable for us to use the smallest error possible right?

Comment: It depends on the wording, and I find "get the error for $n = 2$" ambiguous. In my view that particular wording could mean either "find an error bound for the second-order Taylor approximation", in which case you may as well report the tighter bound, or "find the error bound that Lagrange's remainder produces for $n = 2$", in which case one is referring to that the $n = 2$ bound specifically.

Comment: I thought that's the only instruction but then it want me to show that the error is of $O(x^4)$. Clearly I have to use $n=3$ case or else I can't see how $x^3$ function is $O(x^4)$ in the origin.

Comment: Yes, certainly. Regardless of the coefficient that appears there, the remainder formula shows that the Taylor polynomial $P_n$ of degree $n$ of a function at a point $a$ has error $O((x - a)^{n + 1})$, so showing that the error is $O(x^4)$ just means showing that the third-order coefficient of the Taylor series is zero, so that $P_2 = P_3$.